# CSS get div left position before a transformation

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, getboundingclientrect

Given :

```js
const display = document.querySelector('.display');
const container = document.querySelector('.outer-div');

document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  if (!event.target.closest("button")) return;
  
  if(event.target.id === "button") {

    if(event.target.textContent === "left"){
        console.log("before : " + display.getBoundingClientRect().left);
        display.style.transform += "translateX(50px)";
        console.log("after : " + display.getBoundingClientRect().left);
    }
  }
    
});
```

```css
.meta-div {
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden; /* allows the border-radius to be visible. */
  width: 14rem;
}
.outer-div {
  color: black;
  text-overflow: normal;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: right;
}

.display {
  float:right;
  transition: transform 250ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="meta-div">
  <div class="outer-div">
    <div class="display">111 + 222 + 333 + 444 + 555 + 666 + 777 + 888 + 999</div>
  </div>
</div>
 <button id="button">left</button>
```

my goal is to extract the `display` div left position relative to its container before and after the transformation : `display.style.transform += "translateX(50px)";`.

---

I understand that the function `.getBoundingClientRect()` returns dimensions and location of elements as floating-point numbers *after performing CSS transforms*, so here I should use some other function to extract the position *before* the transformation. Looking at the 3 other questions on SO, the solution seems to use `offsetLeft` but in my case `console.log(display.offsetLeft)` just returns `-127` on every successive `left` button click, while it is supposed to be incrementing by 50 pixels.

I don't know how to extract the div's left position before the `translateX()` transformation. I have been spending long hours on this.

Does anyone have an idea or hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using `transition` animation, you'll need listen for `transitionend` event:

```js
const display = document.querySelector('.display');
const container = document.querySelector('.outer-div');

document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  if (!event.target.closest("button")) return;
  
  if(event.target.id === "button") {

    if(event.target.textContent === "left"){
        console.log("before : " + display.getBoundingClientRect().left);
        display.style.transform += "translateX(50px)";
    }
  }
    
});

display.addEventListener('transitionend', e => {
  console.log("after : " + display.getBoundingClientRect().left);
});
```

```css
.meta-div {
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden; /* allows the border-radius to be visible. */
  width: 14rem;
}
.outer-div {
  color: black;
  text-overflow: normal;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: right;
}

.display {
  float:right;
  transition: transform 250ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="meta-div">
  <div class="outer-div">
    <div class="display">111 + 222 + 333 + 444 + 555 + 666 + 777 + 888 + 999</div>
  </div>
</div>
 <button id="button">left</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your console logs are showing the same result is that you have a `transition` on `transform` property of `250ms`. Your console logs fire near simultaneously, so the property never has time to change between them.

Try deleting line 17 from your css: `transition: transform 250ms;`

You will notice that the console logs show the expected output.

```
before : -119.015625
after : -69.015625

before : -69.015625
after : -19.015625

before : -19.015625
after : 30.984375
```

If you need the transition, and the transformation is always 50px, why not simply hardcode the difference in the values?

Comment: Keep in mind a lot of times people post stripped down samples of their codes, so "hardcode" values is almost never a right answer ;)

Comment: Ah I appreciate the feedback. I assumed OP needed both values instantaneously. I did not know about the `transitionend` event. Thanks for the lesson :D